# calculating volume by integration

Tags: integration, volume

My question might seem silly but i want to calculate the volume of a $3D$ shape by integrating the function using the disk method , But the challenge is that I want to check my result physically by measuring the volume of water inside that shape. I still have two issues to solve , first I need an object that perfectly matches my function , say $y = \sqrt{x} $, from $x = 0$ to $x = 10.$ the second issue is how to make my integration intervals matches with the dimension  of the object.
Please help 1

Comment: Why don't you use a regular cylinder, cone or sphere?

Comment: because my task is to find the volume of a soup cup. beside i need to know what is the value of my integration intervals in the real world !

Comment: Sorry to say this, but the question is incredibly silly. If you want a cup which has exact measurements as you want, the best way is to use a 3D printer, and print whatever shape you want.